# PIR sensor outputs HIGH for too many seconds

Tags: esp8266, pir

I've a pretty simple set up which consists of a PIR sensor and ESP8266.
This PIR sensor outputs a HIGH value when presence is detected. This HIGH value lasts for 8 seconds.

I want this trigger to wake up a ESP8266 chip from a deep sleep. To do so, I must send a LOW to the RST Pin.

So with a NPN transistor, I switch it LOW once PIR outputs HIGH.

This works. However, as the HIGH lasts for 8 seconds, the RST remains in LOW and the ESP does not boot until it's back to HIGH.

So question is: Is there any way to convert this long output to become a fast "trigger"?

I attach an screenshot of the schematics in case it helps.
[image]
(credit of the picture: https://github.com/rgrokett/ESP8266_PIRv2/blob/master/ESP8266_PIRv2.pdf)

Comment: you might consider using ESPNOW so that you can fire off a message 200ms from power-on, instead of seconds with wifi, which is likely why you want to sleep in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think will create enough of a blip to reset the ESP:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhBZJi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This also makes use of a capacitor to do so, as Turbo J suggested in an other answer. How does it differ with his? What is R2 resistance used for?

Comment: It acts as a pulldown and adjustment option together with C1. Turbos version is connected to the collector of a transistor switch. As he said, slight risk of burning the clamping diode with that setup...

Answer (score 2):

Kind of a hack: Use a capacitor between transistor collector and RST pin. Try using 100nF as a starting value - might need to go higher.

Note that this assumes there is a clamping diode between RST and VCC on the ESP8266, as the capacitor would raise RST above VCC when the transistor turns off. Better don't use a large capacity value here - these diodes don't like too much current.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly you will find a rotary potentiometer in the side of your PIR Sensor PCB. Try decreasing its value and you will find the time has been decreased.

Also refer to [This Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7sfcP4nlhM), I think it will help

Comment: I'm using one without rotary potentiometer. MH SR505

Comment: MH SR505 does have a built in delay of 8 Seconds, this means that once the output signal is high it takes 8 seconds to go back low again so you have to try another solution or a different PIR Sensor.